# Allow Users to Sell Products on Django Site

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I'm looking to make a website where users can upload digital items and sell them for a profit. Is there any kind of plugin where users can set up a shop(similar to Etsy), and link bank info(Account Number/Routing Number) for direct deposits? 
I am already using Stripe to charge for a subscription service, so maybe incorporating that could be an option? Anything would really help. Thanks

Comment: Stripe us by far the easiest option - [pinax-stripe](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe) is a great app for Django to take one off payments or subscriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for some sort of escrow marketplace system -

Here's a few a places I have searched in the past:

1. Braintree Marketplace (supports US only) (https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-au/products-and-features/braintree-marketplace)
2. Promisepay (https://promisepay.com/)
3. Stripe Connect (https://stripe.com/connect)
4. Payoneer (https://escrow.payoneer.com/segments/marketplaces)

Your best bet when using financing APIs like the above is to have knowledge of REST architecture and utilise python's `requests` module. If you're lucky, service providers or the community might have already made python wrappers/plugins for you (eg. Stripe, Braintree).